# import tensorflow SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: macos, tensorflow

[image]

Using Virtualenv on Mac I have encountered the showing SyntaxError when I 
import tensorflow 
I tried many times uninstall but now working... please help me!

Comment: Why put an image of text?  You can cut-paste text in here.  See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: We see Stackoverflow as a knowledge base, searchable by everyone interested. Therefore, we prefer the real text above a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow is not supported on Python 3.7. You'll need to use python3.6 or earlier.

async which was fine as a variable name in earlier versions of Python, is a keyword in Python 3.7. This is why it is failing to import.

Comment: That was an old answer :) As of TensorFlow 1.13.1, python 3.7 is now supported.